# How to convert String to Time in PYSPARK?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

iam trying to convert string to Time, but getting NULL.

For Ex,
val Start =='080000'

used the below steps,

```
1)unix_timestamp(col('Start'),'HH:mm:ss'),\
2)to_timestamp(lit('Start'),'HH:mm:ss'),\
3)to_timestamp(col('Start'),'HH:mm:ss'),\
4)from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col('Start'),'HH:mm:ss'))
```

**Expected Output :**

08:00:00 (HH:MM:SS)

could someone please suggest the methods

Comment: But,while performing code migration sql to Pyspark, i have a requirement to calculate start time & End time. How to handle these scenario?

Comment: Simple, Need to convert a string to TIME in Pyspark

Answer (score 1):

Spark does have `TimeType`. Latest version v3.1.1 only has `DateType` and `TimestampType`, so the simple answer to your request converting String to Time is impossible.

However, it's possible to convert from `080000` (StringType) to `2000-01-01 08:00:00` (TimestampType) – or any date as the date doesn't matter – and you can perform any kind of date comparison you want

```py
(df
    .withColumn('from_timestamp', F.regexp_replace(F.col('from'), '(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '2000-01-01 $1:$2:$3'))
    .withColumn('to_timestamp', F.regexp_replace(F.col('to'), '(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '2000-01-01 $1:$2:$3'))
    .withColumn('diff', F.to_timestamp(F.col('to_timestamp')) - F.to_timestamp(F.col('from_timestamp')))
    .show()
)

# +------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
# |  from|    to|     from_timestamp|       to_timestamp|      diff|
# +------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
# |080000|083000|2000-01-01 08:00:00|2000-01-01 08:30:00|30 minutes|
# +------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
```